# Copy html files from source directory to build directory

Tags: web, gnu-make, web-frontend

I'm writing a makefile for a website.

I have a directory called `src/` and `build/`

Basically, I want to take files like this:

```
src/index.html
src/blog/title1/index.html
src/blog/title2/index.html
```

And copy them to the `build/` directory like this:

```
build/index.html
build/blog/title1/index.html
build/blog/title2/index.html
```

I tried writing a rule, but I'm not really sure how to debug this:

```
src_html := src/**/*.html
build_html := $(shell find src -name '*.html' | sed 's/src/build/')

$(src_html): $(build_html)
    @cp $< $@
```

Comment: First of all, you should use 1 * instead of two when wildcard matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use rsync if you have it installed.

```
default:
        rsync -r --include '*/' --include='*.html' --exclude='*' src/ build/
```

Comment: Damn this is a nice solution, I guess I'll have to do a `man rsync`. +1 for elegant scripting!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

# get htm files
find . -name '*html' > files

# manipulate file location
sed 's/src/build/' files | paste files - > mapping

# handle spaces in the file names
sed 's/ /\\ /' mapping > files

# output mapping to be sure.
cat files
echo "Apply mapping?[Y/n]"
read reply
[[ $reply =~ [Yy].* ]] || exit 1
# copy files from column one to column two
awk '{ system("cp "$1" "$2)}' files

exit 0
```

**Edit**

No wait I have a one liner:

```
$ find -name '*html' -exec bash -c 'file=$(echo {}); file=$(echo $file | sed "s:\/:\\\/:g"); cp "{}" $(echo ${file/src/build} | sed "s:\\\/:\/:g")' \;
```

Comment: Just use the really really useful _mmv_ command `mmv -vcd 'src/;*.html' 'build/#1#2.html'`

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing that command, I will definitely look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, *make* can handle this fine with static pattern rules:

```
src := src/index.html src/blog/title1/index.html src/blog/title2/index.html
# or src := $(shell find …) etc., but hopefully the makefile already has a list

dst := $(patsubst src/%,build/%,${src})
${dst}: build/%: src/% ; cp $< $@

.PHONY: all
all: ${dst}
```

This is `-j` safe too, as well as not copying files that have not been updated.